# removing the first character in a text file using Sed

Tags: bash, text, sed

I have 100s of enormous text files in the form of

```
p 127210 3240293 23423234 3242323423
3242323 23423423 23423234 32423423
```

which I want to turn to

```
127210 3240293 23423234 3242323423
3242323 23423423 23423234 32423423
```

I've tried using

```
sed '1 s/^.//' input > output
```

but that gives me

```
 127210 3240293 23423234 3242323423
3242323 23423423 23423234 32423423
```

i.e. an annoying space where the p was. Can anyone help me modify the sed expression to get the output without the space?

Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/^. //' input > output` ?

Comment: The command you ran should also have removed the `3` at the beginning of the 2nd line. Why wasn't that line affected?

Comment: missed the 1 befre the s

Comment: @sam : Please format the input to how it appear in the text file.. Your input format doesn't make any sense as of now given you `sed` command and result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '!/^[0-9]+/{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1} 1'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Checking condition `!/^[0-9]+/` which will check if a line doesn't start from digits then do following, then I am nullifying first field here(because you don't want `p` in output here), then I am re-arranging `$0`(current line) and re-arranging `$1` too so that it could remove that initial space as per your request here.

Output will be as follows.

```
127210 3240293 23423234 3242323423
3242323 23423423 23423234 32423423
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^[[:alpha:]]?//;s/^[[:space:]]*//' infile >outifle
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/^. //' foo.txt > foo2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove non-numeric characters at the beginning of the lines:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*//' input > output
```